# Reading unknown number of integers from a file

Tags: c, file, scanf, feof

This is a function that reads an unknown number of integers from a file and calculates the average. For some reason the last element in the file is being read twice. Can someone please explain why? I know how to fix it but would like to know what goes on behind the scenes.

```
int total = 0, count = 0, input;
FILE *filePtr;

filePtr = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if (filePtr != NULL)
    do
    {
        fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &input);
        total = total + input;
        count++;
    } while (!feof(filePtr));

printf ("%d", total);
```

I fixed it by putting a second `if` in the loop:

```
    do
    {
        fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &input);
        if (!feof(filePtr))
        {
            total = total + input;
            count++;
        }
    } while (!feof(filePtr));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking that `fscanf` actually finds a number. The last call will fail because you're most likely just reading in the last line break in the file.

Try this:

```
do
{
    if (fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &input)==1) {
        total = total + input;
        count++;
    }
} while (!feof(filePtr));
```

**EDIT:** @Andrew is right — you should really check for an EOF at the top of the loop:

```
while (!feof(filePtr)) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't reading anything twice. Your last call to `fscanf` fails because there is nothing to read. Since your original code doesn't check the return value of this function (equal to the number of items read), you are adding the value from the previous iteration. The suggested `if()` statement above will fix this.

Comment: Ok I get it. Adding `input = 0;` before the end of the loop would also help. Which way is better?

Comment: Adding `input = 0;` would not help because you would still be incrementing the value of `count` and calculating the wrong average value.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you shouldn't use a `do-while loop`.  Basically, you're reading from the file THEN checking for end of file.  What if there are 0 `ints`? You'll try reading BEFORE you check to see if the file is at the end.

Also, you're not checking the result of `fscanf`. It reports if it was successful or not...

Answer (score 1):

The `do-while` structure cause this side effect, because it first reads the data, so the condition is checked just after the code inside the loop is executed. Try to use the `while` structure to avoid reading the last item twice, you will no longer need to do the `if` test inside the loop.

```
while (!feof(filePtr)){
    fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &input);
    total = total + input;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: This probably happened because you have an empty line at the end. You can improve your code by validating this and also validating whether what you're reading is really a number or not.

Comment: Code wasn't actually reading value twice. It was just using the previous value again since fscanf did not work before it.

Answer (score 1):

from [feof documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/):
"Notice that stream's internal position indicator may point to the end-of-file for the next operation, but still, the end-of-file indicator may not be set until an operation attempts to read at that point."

So even if you read the last int in the file the pointer indicates to EOF, but because no one attempted to read again feof does not indicate that the file end is reached.

I think that the same value is 'read twice' because the variable is not changed and it holds the same value as the last one read.